# in-app-calendar for Windows 10 UWP

Tags: c#, calendar, win-universal-app, windows-10

I am looking for a calendar control to display a schedule for Windows 10 UWP with the possibility to add and remove events.

I thought the new CalendarPanel or CalendarView was a in-app-calendar, but that's only for selecting a date.

Is this possible or have I to build that by myself?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, UWP built-in controls are mostly for selecting a date. With `CalendarView`, you can have some limited customization options and display the indication of event frequency on a given date using color bars (see [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/calendar-view) for details).

If you want more customizable calendar control, you can try some third-party controls, like [the one from Syncfusion](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/uwp/calendar) or [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/universal-windows-platform-ui#).